Missing a step? Using arrays (req'd) to convert HexString to Decimal (Int)
So every variation I've coded keeps coming back with 0 or 1 regardless of what I input. Excuse the length/inefficiency, just trying to make it work.
v1 - if/else tests
        System.out.println("Enter a hexadecimal String to convert to decimal (base_10)");
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Hexadecimal >> ");
            String hex = scan.nextLine();
            
            String hexArray[] = hex.split("");
            //int hexNum[] = new int[hexArray.length];
            
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hexArray)); //test
            int sum = 0;
            int exp = 0;
            for (int i = hexArray.length-1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if(hexArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
                    sum += 10 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                else if(hexArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
                    sum += 11 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                else if(hexArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                    sum += 12 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                else if(hexArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
                    sum += 13 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                else if(hexArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
                    sum += 14 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                else if(hexArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
                    sum += 15 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                else
                    sum += (Integer.parseInt(hexArray[i]) * Math.pow(16,exp));
                exp++;
            }
            System.out.println("\nHexadecimal: " + hex + "\t Decimal: " + sum);
        }

Alternatively...
v2 - switch by String
        System.out.println("Enter a hexadecimal String to convert to decimal (base_10)");
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Hexadecimal >> ");
            String hex = scan.nextLine();
            
            String[] hexArray = hex.split("");
            
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hexArray)); //test
            int sum = 0;
            int exp = 0;
            for (int i = hexArray.length-1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                String s = hexArray[i];
                switch(s)
                {
                    case "A":   case "a":
                         sum += (10 * Math.pow(16,exp));
                         break;
                    case "B":   case "b":
                         sum += (11 * Math.pow(16,exp));
                         break;
                    case "C":   case "c":
                         sum += (12 * Math.pow(16,exp));
                         break;
                    case "D":   case "d":
                         sum += (13 * Math.pow(16,exp));
                         break;
                    case "E":   case "e":
                         sum += (14 * Math.pow(16,exp));
                         break;
                    case "F":   case "f":
                        System.out.println("hi");
                         sum += (15 * Math.pow(16,exp));
                         break;
                    default:    //i.e. NUMBERS
                         sum += ((Integer.parseInt(hexArray[i]) * Math.pow(16,exp)));
                }
                exp++;
            }
            System.out.println("\nHexadecimal: " + hex + "\t Decimal: " + sum);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

v3 - switch with char-literals
        System.out.println("Enter a hexadecimal String to convert to decimal (base_10)");
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Hexadecimal >> ");
            String hex = scan.nextLine();
            
            String[] hexArray = hex.split("");
            
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hexArray)); //test
            int sum = 0;
            int exp = 0;
            for (int i = hexArray.length-1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                char c = hexArray[i].charAt(0);
                switch(c)
                {
                    case '0':
                        break;
                    case '1':
                        sum += Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        sum += 2 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        sum += 3 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        sum += 4 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        sum += 5 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case '6':
                        sum += 6 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case '7':
                        sum += 7 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case '8':
                        sum += 8 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case '9':
                        sum += 9 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':
                        sum += 10 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case 'B':
                    case 'b':
                        sum += 11 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                    case 'c':
                        sum += 12 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                    case 'd':
                        sum += 13 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                    case 'e':
                        sum += 14 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    case 'F':
                    case 'f':
                        sum += 15 * Math.pow(16,exp);
                        break;
                    default:
                        ;   //Invalid Character
                }
                exp++;
            }
            System.out.println("\nHexadecimal: " + hex + "\t Decimal: " + sum);

Multiple ways (shown above) , but initially splitting it into an array and reading backwards R->L to increment the exponent accordingly.

Just to say, you can of course do String convertedToDecimal = new BigInteger(hex, 16);

In all versions of your code (v1, v2, and v3), the loop condition is i > 0. This means that the loop will stop when i becomes 1, and then it will skip the first element in your hexArray (at index 0).
Simply change the loop condition to this:
for (int i = hexArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)


Thank you, I feel stupid. Went over each several times and was like--ok my logic HAS to be sound, what if...

@Skelefish My pleasure to help. You dont need to write SOLVED on your question. You can just accept the answer with a button near answer✔️

Appreciate it, very new to actually posting here and not just lurking. :)

Your approach is reasonable and a common way to achieve the goal (all have some variations).
By multiplying each stage of the ultimate answer you can implicitly work in the powers of 16.  Here is an example.

establish a string of hexDigits
then iterate over the hexValue to be converted, finding the index of the digit.
converting to uppercase allows both cases for hex digits (a-f)
the compute an iterative sum by mulitplying by the hex base of 16

String hexDigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";

String hexValue = "12FFA";

long decimal = 0;
for (char hexDigit : hexValue.toCharArray()) {
    decimal = decimal * 16 + hexDigits.indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(hexDigit));
}
System.out.println(decimal);

prints
77818

Here is how it is working

decimal = 0
decimal = decimal * 16 + 1 ( decimal = 0 + 1 = 1)
decimal = decimal * 16 + 2 ( decimal = 16 + 2 = 18)
decimal = decimal * 16 + 15 ( decimal = 288 + 15 = 303)
decimal = decimal * 16 + 15 ( decimal = 4848 + 15 = 4863)
decimal = decimal * 16 + 10 ( decimal = 4863 + 10 = 77818)

Note that I am using a long for the answer.  The max value for a long in hex is 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
